# jQuery custom plugin used with .on()

Tags: jquery

I'm using a custom plugin (below) that fires when a user stops/pauses typing. The plugin works fine when used like `$(elm).donetyping(function(){//do something});`, however, I wondering if it's possible to use it with `.on()`  as I need to use it with some dynamically loaded content i.e.

```
$(elm).on("donetyping", "elm2", function(){//do something});
```

The plugin is:

```
 (function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        donetyping: function(callback, timeout) {
            timeout = timeout || 1e3; // 1 second default timeout
            var timeoutReference,
                    doneTyping = function(el) {
                if (!timeoutReference)
                    return;
                timeoutReference = null;
                callback.call(el);
            };
            return this.each(function(i, el) {
                var $el = $(el);
                // Chrome Fix (Use keyup over keypress to detect backspace)
                // thank you @palerdot
                $el.is(':input') && $el.on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
                    // This catches the backspace button in chrome, but also prevents
                    // the event from triggering too premptively. Without this line,
                    // using tab/shift+tab will make the focused element fire the callback.
                    if (e.type == 'keyup' && e.keyCode != 8)
                        return;

                    // Check if timeout has been set. If it has, "reset" the clock and
                    // start over again.
                    if (timeoutReference)
                        clearTimeout(timeoutReference);
                    timeoutReference = setTimeout(function() {
                        // if we made it here, our timeout has elapsed. Fire the
                        // callback
                        doneTyping(el);
                    }, timeout);
                }).on('blur', function() {
                    // If we can, fire the event since we're leaving the field
                    doneTyping(el);
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I've had a look around google but I don't think I'm searching for the right terms. Any help or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `.on` is used to handle events. You'll need to change your plugin to fire a `donetyping` event and then register a callback to that handler.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/

Comment: no.. it is not possible... `.on()` is only for event handler... for dynamically added elements, you need to initialize the plugin once those elements are created

Comment: I could use the 2nd param of `.on` for dynamic content as all the elements are loaded in to an element that existed when the document was loaded.

Comment: Sorry, @ArunPJohny I see what you mean now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.on` is used to handle events. You'll need to change your plugin to fire a custom event called `donetyping` and then register a callback to that handler.

Change your doneTyping method to this: (adds trigger)

```
doneTyping = function(el) {
  if (!timeoutReference) return;
  timeoutReference = null;
  if (callback) {
    callback.call(el);
  }
  $(el).trigger('donetyping');
};
```

And then try this:

```
$(document).on('donetyping', '.dynamic-element', function() {
  console.log('done typing on ', $(this));
});
```

Comment: It works, but I have to initalize the element to the plugin before hand i.e. `$(elm).donetyping();` then your answer. IDo you know if it's possible to initalize the plugin with the `.on()` call or in the method?

Comment: No, the plugin has to be registered before, so it will know to fire the event. You do that with something like `$(function() { $('input:text').donetyping(); })`

Comment: Fair enough, thank you very much for your help and also your explanation!